# how to add to table select checkboxes as a columns

Tags: jquery

Here I have a popup with checkboxes. When I selected checkbox in table1 based on indexes displayed in table2 with in popup, those should add the as column in outside of the popup table.

(Popup window having multiple checkboxes, I have to select couple of checkboxes and click the submit button to add column in table).

In my below code adding to the table which is outside of the popup table not working on button click:

```
var cell = $(this).parent("td");
var row = $(cell).parent("tr");
var rowIndex = $('#popout th[id=' + thisId + ']').index();
var columnIndex = (rowIndex);
var tblcolumnscount = $('#popout td').length;
if $('#popout td').length == 0) {
    var colselect = 1;
    $('#popout td,#tblKPLItemList th').addClass('hide');
    $('#popout-l td,#tblKPLItemList-sticky th').addClass('hide');
    $('#popout ,tblKPLItemList-sticky').removeClass('hide');
    $('#popout td:nth-child(' + (colselect + 1) + '),#popout th:nth-child(' + (colselect + 1) + ')').removeClass('hide');
    $('#popout-l td:nth-child(' + (colselect + 1) + '),#popout-l th:nth-child(' + (colselect + 1) + ')').removeClass('hide');
}

if (checked) {
    var Fid = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    if (Fid == 'ColumnsSelect') {
        var Checkedrow = $(this).closest('tr').html();
        $('#tblpopup2 tbody').append('<tr class="' + thisId + '">' + Checkedrow + '</tr>');
        $("#tblpopup2 tbody input").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
$('#popout td:nth-child(' + (columnIndex + 1) + '),.display th:nth-child(' + (columnIndex + 1) + ')').removeClass('hide');
$('#popout-l td:nth-child(' + (columnIndex + 1) + '),#popout-l th:nth-child(' + (columnIndex + 1) + ')').removeClass('hide');
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for this?

Comment: i dont find any html code in the fiddle..